# ASP.NET Entity Framework - Create Trigger Programatically

Tags: ef-code-first

I posted this question on the ASP.NET forums, and was eventually directed to post the same question here.

Original asp.net forums post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1774923.aspx/1?Database+Generated+DateTimes

I'm trying to add CreatedDate and ModifedDate to my Code First models. If this were database first I would have added a GETDATE() default value to both of these. A few options were presented on how to do this using C.F.. However, I think the cleanest suggestion was to use triggers to manage these date fields.

Is there a way to manage the creation of triggers using the E.F./C.F. so that I don't have to re-create them every time my model changes?

ricka6 from the asp.net forums suggested I include the following post as it may be related: [Mapping many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470302/mapping-many-to-many-relationship/9470506#9470506)

Thank you!
  -Walker

Answer (score 0):

Try using EF 4.3 with [database migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx), so your database won't be recreated every time your model changes. Alternatively, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031431/entity-framework-ctp-4-code-first-custom-database-initializer) for ideas how to create custom database initializer.